# Are there any differences between Spelunky HD player characters?

Tags: spelunky-hd

Is there any benefit or detriment to selecting different player characters in Spelunky HD? Or is it simply cosmetic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, all of the characters are just 'palette swaps' of a base character. They all function in the same way. The differences are purely cosmetic, both for player amusement and so players can easily tell the difference between each other in co-op or arena.